# Binding Telerik RadRichTextBox through MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, richtextbox

I can't seem to pick my way through Telerik's terrible documentation for binding through an MVVM situation.  We've got the standard view, and view model.  The viewmodel exposes a property, 'Body' that is supposed to represent what the user is typing.  Here are the relevant lines of xaml:

```
<telerik:DocxDataProvider 
    x:Name="DocxProvider" 
    RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=editor}" 
    Docx="{Binding Body, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"   />
<telerik:RadRichTextBox 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    x:Name="editor" 
    Margin="0" 
    AllowDrop="True" 
    ShowComments="False" 
    MinWidth="800" 
    MinHeight="300" 
    MaxWidth="1024" 
    MaxHeight="1200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
    Width="790" 
    Padding="20,20,0,20" 
    TabIndex="10"  
    Cursor="IBeam" 
    IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" >
</telerik:RadRichTextBox>
```

But when I set a break point on Body, it never gets hit.  What property do I need to bind to so that my view model actually gets the content of the text box?

Comment: @l33t Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to `Rtf` property of `telerik:RadRichTextBox`; another thing can be the ordering of your elements, can you try declaring `<telerik:RadRichTextBox` before `<telerik:DocxDataProvider`

Also have a look at this thread on telerik forum -

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/richtextbox/binding-document.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Rtf property on the RadRichTextBox...only the RtfDataProvdier class.  And we've tried reordering things, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set the datacontext in the constructor of the xaml.cs file:

```
    public View(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

This is how you hook up the viewmodel to the view.